# Is it true that the minimum value of kurtosis for any distribution is -2?

Tags: probability-distributions

The [Bernoulli distritbution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) has excess kurtosis = $-2$. In addition for a symmetric [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with $\alpha = \beta$ the excess kurtossis is $-6/(2\alpha+3)$ whose minimum value is again $-2$.

But, how can it be shown whether this is the minimum possible value for all conceivable probability distributions?

Answer (score 2):

Use Jensen's inequality: Let $Z = (X-\mu)/\sigma$. Then (non-excess) kurtosis is $\kappa = E(Z^4) \ge \{E(Z^2)\}^2 =1$.  Subtract 3 to get excess kurtosis and you have the result. Of course this assumes finite fourth moment.